# Perl best way to compare two lists of dates & numbers

Tags: sql, arrays, perl, hash

I'm not sure where to start so I will start at the beginning. I have two lists containing two columns each. A date/time column and a number column in the following format:

```
2012-11-27 13:16:19.473           6
2012-11-27 13:17:17.910         710
2012-11-28 15:21:52.513         696
2012-11-29 08:40:16.430         541
2012-11-20 09:07:45.813         347
2012-12-01 01:00:09.230         647
2012-12-01 14:53:22.200         488
2012-12-04 18:42:02.727         797
```

The date/times are always unique but the 2nd column has duplicates in both lists. I first need to compare the 2nd column of the first list to the 2nd column of the second list. Each time a match is found in the second column I need to compare the corresponding dates. If the dates are within (+ or -) 5 days of each other I need to subtract them and find the difference in hours, then count how many occurrences of each difference there is.

For example:

List 1:

```
2014-03-27 17:00:00.000         582
2012-12-04 18:42:02.727         797
```

List 2:

```
2014-03-28 17:00:00.000         582
2012-12-04 18:42:02.727         793
```

The required output would be 1 occurrence of 24 hours.

I'm unsure as to the best way to store the lists which are coming out of a database. Hashes with the date as the key because the 2nd column has duplicates or arrays or arrays of arrays or... help me!

Thank you!

Comment: Please give an example of how to handle the case where multiple records have the same value in column 2 and also match a value in the other file. How are partial hours to be handled? Do you want them rounded to the nearest hour? When you ask to *"count how many occurrences of each difference"*, does that mean you want a summary at the end of processing all of the data, or after each match found?

Comment: Column 1 of both lists have timestamps, column 2 of both lists have id's. Foreach line in list 1: compare the id to each id in list 2. For every match found, compare the corresponding timestamps. If the timestamps are within 5 days of each other, find the difference in hours (rounded to the nearest hour) and provide a summary at the end of processing all of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question, what's the easiest way to compare to dates?

I'd suggest using [`Time::Piece`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my $str1 = '2014-03-27 17:00:00';
my $str2 = '2014-03-28 17:00:00';

my $t1 = Time::Piece->strptime($str1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
my $t2 = Time::Piece->strptime($str2, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');

print "$t1\n";
print "$t2\n";

my $diff = $t2 - $t1;

print "$diff\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

[Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) is a useful module but cannot do sub-seconds calculations. You'll probably need to use [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.08/lib/DateTime.pm) module.

Here is one way to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

# Set the pattern for your timestamp 

my $dp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N');

open my $fh1, '<', "List1";
open my $fh2, '<', "List2";

my %ids;  
my ($ts, $id);

# Read List1 and create a hash with id as keys and timestamp as values

while (<$fh1>) {
    ($ts, $id) = /(\S+\s\S+)\s+(\S+)/;  
    $ids{$id} = $ts; 
}

# Read the second file and check if id exists in hash

while (<$fh2>) {
    ($ts, $id) = /(\S+\s\S+)\s+(\S+)/;
    if (exists $ids{$id}) {

# If the id is present we find the difference of timestamp and print it

        my $diff = $dp->parse_datetime($ts)-$dp->parse_datetime($ids{$id});
        print "Difference found for id " . $id . "\n";
        print 
        $diff->days . " Day(s) " . 
        $diff->hours . " Hour(s) " . 
        $diff->minutes . " Minute(s) " . 
        $diff->seconds . " Second(s) " . "\n";
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
Difference found for id 582
1 Day(s) 0 Hour(s) 0 Minute(s) 0 Second(s)
```

Comment: There are duplicate ids in the lists with different timestamps. Is it not correct that a hash cannot have duplicate keys?

Comment: @GerryVK Correct, but you haven't stated how to calculate time when duplicate ids occur in the list?

Comment: Both lists will have duplicate id's but the timestamps will be separated by more than 5 days. To clarify: Column 1 of both lists have timestamps, column 2 of both lists have id's. Foreach line in list 1: compare the id to each id in list 2. For every match found, compare the corresponding timestamps. If the timestamps are within 5 days of each other, find the difference in hours.